# Page exists, google bot returning 404 error

Tags: googlebot

I have website which is online. When I'am using it via browser everything is ok and this page is present in browser. When I'm using it as googlebot ( via webmastertools ) i'm getting error

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 19 Nov 2012 09:57:37 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: symfony=55240a0a341202d07fc96cbc1c1bcca5; path=/
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=200
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

and rest of the html code...
```

same thing when I'm trying to validate it via wc3 validator.

Please help :( I tryied everything :(

website address is mojaczestochowa.pl

If more info is needed please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check the pae with [web-sniffer](http://web-sniffer.net/) and set user agent to google.bot

Comment: I got same answare as webmastertools :( any other idea ?

Comment: Can u get link? Look like you site return HTTP404 based on user-agent. May be some plugin in your cms do that, if you are using some of them.

Comment: when Im trying to get link and getting error404 and code site code following that error. No plugins, code written in symfony 1.4

Comment: Try to use symfony2. 1.4 very old. Check .htaccess and routes list - may be you realy doesn't have this page.

Comment: only main page is genereting 404 error please see .htacccess below

   `RewriteEngine On`
   `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mojaczestochowa.pl(.*) [NC]`
   `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mojaczestochowa.pl/$1 [R=301,L]`
  `RewriteBase /`
  `RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]`
  `RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]`
  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]`

Comment: What do You mean by site configuration ? this code is wrong ? only ... index.php is responding with error 404

Comment: I have many other sites with same .htaccess confi this is nightmare only this page is giving this error

Comment: Stupid mistake! i used homepage as my error404 site. Symfony was generating this header. Thanks a lot for Your time!

Comment: as most of the time the web-sniffer.net is either offline or dysfunctional, here is a similar [websniffer tool](https://websniffer.cc/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the exact query, which will simulate server's response to the GoogleBot crawler:
https://websniffer.cc/?url=http://mojaczestochowa.pl/&uak=9